# Listpicker is not bind after async call in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hi Listpicker not binding proper items.it binding project name list if i use async method.In case if i use same code inside constructor it working perfectly.

i tried this code:

c#:

```
List<Orderlist> GetOrderItems = new List<Orderlist>();
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

            var resultOrderReq = await this.objOrderMgr.GetOrders(objOrderReq, this.objRequestHeaderHelper.GetRequestHeaders());
            var reslistOrder = resultOrderReq.orderlist;
            foreach (var item in reslistOrder)
            {
                GetOrderItems.Add(new Orderlist() { OrderId = item.orderid });
            }
            this.ProductSub.ItemsSource = GetOrderItems;
        }
    }
    public class Orderlist
    {
        public long OrderId { get; set; }

    }
```

XAML

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ProductSub" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}"/>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderId}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderId}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Whats the result you getting. any exception ???

Comment: No exception..simply it displaying project name+class names in list picker instead of items

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a problem like this comes down to one of two things:

- You forgot to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for properties that change.
- You are using a non-observable collection, e.g., `List<T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`.

I can't tell for sure based on your problem description, but it looks like it might be the observable collection problem. Try replacing `List<Orderlist>` with `ObservableCollection<Orderlist>`.

Answer (score 0):

//I made little changes in your code. may this will help you.

```
List<Orderlist> GetOrderItems = new List<Orderlist>();
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {   
       if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
          {
             var resultOrderReq = await this.objOrderMgr.GetOrders(objOrderReq, this.objRequestHeaderHelper.GetRequestHeaders());
             var reslistOrder = resultOrderReq.orderlist;
             foreach (var item in reslistOrder)
               {
                  GetOrderItems.Add(new { OrderId = item.orderid });
               }
            this.ProductSub.ItemsSource = GetOrderItems;
           }
      }



 public class Orderlist
    {
        public long OrderId { get; set; }
    }
```